# Changing the URL dynamically on addthis share bar works on all but the share count

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, addthis

I have a modal on a page that has addthis share buttons in the footer.
I have a list of items on the page, that when clicked, populate the modal with content via ajax.

What I'm doing is dynamically changing the addthis:url and addthis:title on click.

So, here's the modal stripped down to the footer:

```
<div class="modal">
  ...
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
      <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then, when an item is clicked, I'm passing some variables in to change the url and title:

```
addthis.toolbox(".addthis_toolbox", null, { title: theTitle, url: theUrl });
```

The problem is `<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>`

It's the count bubble on the end of:

[image: addthisexample]

The url and title change just fine, but the counter never changes.

I'm submitted a support request to addthis, that of which lacked a decent response, asking if I've called addthis.init(), which yes... of course I did. The sharing bar has been initialized and is working, but counts not updating.

Searching the web and other questions on here, along with the docs on addthis, there are so many intricate ways of dealing with ajax based content.

The difference in my code vs their examples is, the ajax content includes the actual buttons, whereas mine does not. My sharing toolbar remains on the page, and only the addthis:url and addthis:title is changed.

Maybe I'm missing some small step, or perhaps this is a bug and not my fault at all.

Hoping someone might have some insight.

**EDIT**

I got a response finally... from addthis, stating that it wasn't possible. Counts are not refreshed if the toolbox function is called.

But Joseph's workaround shown in comments and answer below solved the issue for now, at least until they provide a more suitable solution.

Comment: I have no experience with addthis using ajax, but maybe the support team were meaning for you to re-init the addthis module.  Have you tried re-running `addthis.init()` after you have changed the URL?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I'll double check this, but was quite sure `addthis.init()` was to be called only once.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yes, only call it once: http://support.addthis.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1293805-using-addthis-asynchronously

Comment: Again, take this with a grain of salt (it's hard to make concrete claims with no development environment available, and I understand that it's not really possible in this situation), but maybe because it's in a modal it's having issues. Their code indicates that you should use a class.  Maybe the code adds a data attribute or some other indicator that the particular code was already processed. Perhaps you could first destroy and recreate the `.addthis_toolbox` HTML element before running `addthis.toolbox()`.  Just guessing at this point. Hopefully someone with addthis experience will chime in.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I appreciate that. I tried this, and this time everything is working except now it doesn't show a count bubble at all. What a mystery.

Comment: OK.  Not sure if this helps either, but I think I've found a workaround.  If you call `addthis.counter` with the configuration object, it seems to pull **a** number.  Still not sure if it's the *right* number, but it's closer: http://jsfiddle.net/fakknu7a/.  Documentation here: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1365325-rendering-tools-with-javascript.  Try typing in facebook.com in the box to see it working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91418/discussion-between-user1447679-and-joseph-marikle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trial and error, it seems that the `addthis.counter` method is the way to refresh the counter.  What little documentation there is on the method only seems to refer to just using the method without any parameters (a [forum post I found](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=61918.0)), which may refresh the counter for static share elements (this is unconfirmed); however, when you add the same attributes that you use for the `addthis.toolbox` method call, it refreshes the counter correctly.  You do have to provide the class for the counter and not the toolbox when you do call the `counter` method. e.g. `addthis.counter('.addthis_counter', null, { url: 'http://example.com'});`  Official documentation can be found here: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1365325-rendering-tools-with-javascript

Here is the code in summary:

#### HTML

```
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<input type="text" value="http://example.com">
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    addthis_config = addthis_config || { };
    addthis_config.pubid = prompt('Provide pubid:');
    addthis.init();

    $('input').on('input',function(){
        $(".addthis_toolbox .addthis_counter").replaceWith('<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>');
        addthis.toolbox(".addthis_toolbox", null, { title: 'test', url: this.value });
        addthis.counter('.addthis_counter', null, { url: this.value });
    }).trigger('input');
});
```

Notice that the javascript prompts you for your pubid.  This is just for the demo, you can change that to `addthis_config.pubid = 'xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';` for your application.

#### Demo

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fakknu7a/1)

Comment: Fantastic find Joseph. They really need to work on that documentation. Appreciate your help very much.